# how to make only few selected years appear using react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I have used this package react-datepicker and using this script:

```
<DatePicker className="form__field customdatefld" selected= 
   {this.state.birthYearForCalender} 
    maxDate={new Date()}  

  onChange={this.birthYearChange} showYearPicker dateFormat="yyyy"/>
```

using the option showYearPicker provides me only years in the display but its also showing future years too which I don't want to display, how to restrict it from displaying.
Package url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
Please guide.

I have provided a snapshot of it below how it look:

[image: My year picker looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Once `maxDate` has been set you can target all disabled years in your css and hide them:

```
.react-datepicker__year-text--disabled {
  visibility: hidden !important; /* container will keep its height */
  display: none !important; /* container will shrink to fit content */
}
```

**Update**

If `maxDate` isn't disabling the dates correctly make sure you're using an up-to-date version of react datepicker. As of writing this that is version `3.1.3` of react datepicker for the npm package. I've noticed that `maxDate` doesn't work for version `3.0.0` for example.

Comment: I Tried your way but it didn't worked. Even that class is not falling that you mentioned.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you should upgrade to the most recent version of react datepicker.